# PyQT5 Clear form button wont clear anything

Tags: python, function, pyqt5

I am trying to create a clear entire form button but I cant seem to get anything to clear at all, I've tried so many combinations and different things online but I can't seem to get anything to clear when I press the clear button nothing happens no matter which form ive used to try and change the code it just wont clear and for some reasons different types of clear functions will cause the continue button (which isnt set to do anything at this time) will crash the whole program hahaha. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
        self.clearButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked= lambda: clearButton())
        self.clearButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 610, 75, 23))
        self.clearButton.setObjectName("clearButton")
        self.continueButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.continueButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 610, 75, 23))
        self.continueButton.setObjectName("continueButton")
        

        def clearButton():
            self.clearButton.clicked.connect(self.plainTextEdit.clear)
```

Comment: Remove that `clearButton()` function and move the connection to the main indentation level of `setupUi`. Also: 1. Always provide a [mre]; 2. never edit a `pyuic` file, instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html); 3. use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: not sure what you mean by move the connection to the main indentation level, i cant really get rid of the lambda and i need the clearButton function because i need this button to clear several widgets. Im not editing a pyuic file i converted it to a py file so not exactly sure what your referring to, i used the designer? again not sure what your talking about as far as i know and all the tutorials ive watched and read you cant code in the designer. in regards to number 1, if i started deleting portions of the code to make a reprex you wouldnt know what i need to clear??

Comment: 1. it means that you must move `self.clearButton.clicked.connect(self.plainTextEdit.clear)` at the same indentation level of the lines above; 2. I never said that you should remove the lambda, but, in fact, you don't need it: `self.action_Exit.triggered.connect(closeWindow)` (**without the parentheses!!!**); by the way, in `closeWindow()` you should ***not*** call `sys.exit(app.exec_())` *again*, but eventually `app.quit()` which, btw, is wrong, as it uses a global reference, and it should be `QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()`; truth is, in reality, you should just directly connect the signal: ->

Comment: -> `self.action_Exit.triggered.connect(QtWidgets.QApplication.quit)`; 4. that "py file" ***is*** the pyuic generated file, and you are not expected to edit it (as clearly written in the comments at the top of that file, which you ignored and removed); I know that *some* tutorials say that it's fine to edit those generated files, but they are just ***wrong***, as it's a terrible practice that almost always leads to problems, errors and a lot of confusion; 5. start by removing things while keeping testing, if it still *reproduces* the issue, you can try to remove something else until it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but im curious you say not to edit it, but how are you supposed to code the buttons or other things to do what you want them to do if your not supposed to edit the file? now with that being said, it doesn't say **Dont Edit it** it says don't edit it unless you know what your doing. I figured it out though and i appreciate your input :)

Comment: The question is: did you *actually* know what you were doing? If you were, you probably didn't have to post the question. I've already given you a link in my first comment that clearly explain how to *properly* use those files. There are *lots* of reasons for which editing is highly discouraged, starting with the fact that whenever you have to change the UI you are forced to merge existing code with the newly generated one, which can become quite a mess as the program grows in complexity. That's a *guaranteed* recipe for failure. This video explains *some* of those issues: youtu.be/XXPNpdaK9WA

Comment: @musicamante you should put that last comment as the answer because that video is perfect! thank you very much for that i never thought to do it that way. All the tutorials ive ever seen theyre editing in that file instead of doing it the way the video shows.

Comment: I also edited my original post to lower the amount of code. showing since it doesnt really need to be run to correct the problem its pretty noticeable now that i realized what my error was. Thanks for all the help today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking at a program written by John Elder from codemy and testing his code i finally got it to work with the following code.

```
self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=lambda: self.clear_it())
self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 610, 75, 23))
self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
```

This function is clearing properly.

```
def clear_it(self):
    self.plainTextEdit_2.clear()
    self.plainTextEdit.clear()
    self.plainTextEdit_4.clear()
    self.plainTextEdit_5.clear()
    self.plainTextEdit_6.clear()
    self.plainTextEdit_7.clear()
    self.plainTextEdit_8.clear()
    self.plainTextEdit_9.clear()
    self.dataBackupNameTextbox.clear()
    self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Comment: I wrote a couple of (extremely polite and reasoned) comments on that specific video, explaining that pyuic-editing wasn't a good suggestion, and providing links to show how those generated files should be properly used. Unfortunately, they were deleted and I'm also apparently blocked from further comments on the whole channel. I've already tried to reach out to John Elder, as I believe that admitting to be wrong is a matter of respect for one's own viewers (especially when related to teaching), as opposite to removing constructive criticism from comments. I hope he will answer, and positively.

Comment: Totally Agree constructive criticism has never hurt anyone :)

Comment: Note: you don't need the lambda if the signal and function arguments are compatible; just don't call it and add the function as a reference to the function: `QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, clicked=self.clear_it)`